# Execute Stored PL/SQL procedure under different database account

Tags: sql, database, oracle, plsql

I'm trying to write a script for a web portal (APEX) that allows a user to change their password on the associated database that they select

I'm trying to write a pl/sql procedure that I can execute over a database link to change the password on that database.

I guess what I am asking is can I connect as a different user within a PL/SQL block and run `alter user identified by` from within that block?

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE CHPWD 
(
  Database IN VARCHAR2  
, Username IN VARCHAR2  
, old_pw IN VARCHAR2  
, new_pw IN VARCHAR2  
) AS 
BEGIN
 /* Something like conn Username/old_pw here 

 then

 alter username identified by new_pw */

END CHPWD;
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The standard approach would be to have the procedure owned by a highly privileged user who can change any password, grant execute on the procedure to the users who should be able to execute it, and place logic in the procedure to implement security restrictions.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the main issue is authenticating the user's password before changing it. I do not think there is a secure method to do this though - the best way to confirm the password would be to, as in your comment, login to the database with it. That requires passing the password to an external script though which would reveal your plain text password to anyone with access to the system.

The other method would be to take the algorithms that people have used to duplicate Oracle's password hashing algorithm - but this is effectively hacked together and liable to be changed:
http://www.petefinnigan.com/weblog/archives/00001097.htm